# Workaround "$digest already in progress" without $timeout

Tags: angularjs

Recently while surfing the web I found a solution for not getting "$digest already in progress" error without $timeout. The solution is bellow:

```
$scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
  var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
  if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
    if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
      fn();
    }
  } else {
    this.$apply(fn);
  }
};
```

I take it from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma/safe-apply-in-angular-js)

My question is: Is this a valid solution? I was wondering what might happen if the scope property changes inside of the fn() has already been digested and the digest is still in progress. In that case changes of the fn() won't have any affect on bindings.

Comment: it should be `$digest already in progress` NOT 'apply already in progress'

Answer (score 0):

You won't find anything cleaner than this hack to handle 'maybe-during-digest' callback, if that's your question.

Real solution would be to fix the root cause of the famous "$digest already in progress" error, by using $timeout with false as last parameter, for example, or _.defer, or so.

Comment: No my question isn't how I can make this code cleaner. My question was is this solution a valid one. And the reason I would prefer to not use $timeout is the performance overhead.

Comment: valid ? nope. Using internal api ( double $ attributes ) which are not documented and not supposed to be used outside of angular core. People seems to be scared of these false "perf issues" about $timeout. If you have more than 100 $timeout trigger in one sec, sure perf will be crappy. but $timeout only executes a $digest on root scope, as every scope's $apply method does, so perf difference is not really significant (based on my experience at least).